# Adding OCX to a WPF project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, ocx

I need to build a C# WPF desktop application using some purchased OCX controls.
I am trying to move to C# from Delphi where these OCX are important components.

I need a basic tut on adding OCXs to Visual Studio 2013 tool box.

Comment: I finally found my way to:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742735.aspx

This is an example of adding Windows Media Player to a WPF project and should help.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found my way to:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742735.aspx

This is an example of adding Windows Media Player to a WPF project and should help.